# railties installed but not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using this SO answer [How do you use multiple rails versions with rbenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877772/how-do-you-use-multiple-rails-versions-with-rbvenv), I'm trying to set up an environment using rbenv (rather than rvm) to manage different versions of Ruby and Rails. The answer first says to install a version of Rails linked to a version of ruby in this manner.

```
RBENV_VERSION=1.9.3-p327 rbenv exec gem install rails --version 3.2.10
```

That worked for me. Rails installed.

Following its instructions, i then tried to create a new project this way using that version of rails

```
RBENV_VERSION=1.9.3-p327 rbenv exec rails _3.10.2_ new newprojectname
```

That didn't work for me. I got an error message about

```
.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (= 3.10.2) amongst [RedCloth-4.2.9, aaronh-chronic-0.3.9, abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.2.10, actionmailer-3.0.4, actionpack-3.2.10, actionpack-3.0.4, activemodel-3.2.10, activemodel-3.2.9, activemodel-3.0.4, activerecord-3.2.10, activerecord-3.0.4, activeresource-3.2.10, activeresource-3.0.4, activesupport-3.2.10, activesupport-3.2.9, activesupport-3.0.4, addressable-2.3.2, arel-3.0.2, arel-2.0.10, bigdecimal-1.1.0, builder-3.0.4, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.2.3, capybara-2.0.2, carrierwave-0.5.8, childprocess-0.3.6, coderay-1.0.8, cucumber-1.2.1, cucumber-rails-1.3.0, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, erubis-2.6.6, factory_girl-4.1.0, ffi-1.2.0, formtastic-2.2.1, gherkin-2.11.5, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.1, io-console-0.3, jist-1.3.1, journey-1.0.4, json-1.7.6, json-1.5.4, lesstile-1.1.0, libwebsocket-0.1.7.1, mail-2.4.4, mail-2.2.19, market_beat-0.2.0, method_source-0.8.1, mime-types-1.19, minitest-2.5.1, multi_json-1.5.0, nokogiri-1.5.6, polyglot-0.3.3, pry-0.9.10, pry-rails-0.2.2, rack-1.4.1, rack-1.2.5, rack-cache-1.2, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-openid-1.3.1, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.2.10, rails-3.0.4, railties-3.2.10, railties-3.0.4, rake-10.0.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4, rspec-2.12.0, rspec-core-2.12.2, rspec-expectations-2.12.1, rspec-mocks-2.12.1, rspec-rails-2.12.0, ruby-openid-2.2.2, rubygems-update-1.8.24, rubyzip-0.9.9, selenium-webdriver-2.27.2, slop-3.3.3, sprockets-2.2.2, sqlite3-1.3.6, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.12, tzinfo-0.3.35, webrat-0.7.3, websocket-1.0.6, will_paginate-3.0.pre2, xpath-1.0.0] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Therefore I tried to install railties

```
gem install railties
```

It worked

```
Successfully installed railties-3.2.10
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for railties-3.2.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for railties-3.2.10...
```

However, trying to create the project again

```
RBENV_VERSION=1.9.3-p327 rbenv exec rails _3.10.2_ new newprojectname
```

created the same error message about railties

```
see error message above
```

I even tried to install railties again but with the RBENV prefix

```
RBENV_VERSION=1.9.3-p327 rbenv exec gem install railties
```

It installed again!, however, when I tried to create the new project, i got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

ive faced the same issue,

this is what i did
i removed ~/.gemrc

next, i ran `gem env`
to see if its pointing to the right place:
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-08 patchlevel -1) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/[yourpath]/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/[yourpath]/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/[yourpath]/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/[yourpath]/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /home/[yourpath]/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/

then i tried to install the gem again

> gem install rails

and now its installing to the right place :)
please let me know if it works for ya